# Error when trying to implement editor.md: Zepto not defined

Tags: javascript, editor.md

I am building a simple blog-application and I try to implement the open source markdown-editor from [this](http://editor.md.ipandao.com) webpage.
But when I try to run their example in the browser, I receive to following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Zepto is not defined
    at editormd.js:43
    at editormd.js:34
    at editormd.js:37
index.html?_ijt=2tq9lqm9cq4av7klja454nu6k2:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at index.html?_ijt=2tq9lqm9cq4av7klja454nu6k2:18
```

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>editorMD Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/editor/editor.md-master/css/editormd.css">
<div id="test-editor">
    <textarea style="display:none;">### Editor.md

**Editor.md**: The open source embeddable online markdown editor, based on CodeMirror & jQuery & Marked.
    </textarea>
</div>
<script src="scripts/editor/editor.md-master/editormd.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        let editor = editormd("#test-editor", {
            width  : "100%",
            height : "100%",
            path   : "scripts/editor/editor.md-master/lib/"
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My file-path should be valid, because I am using WebStorm and it is not showing any path-relevant erros.
Is it possible, that I have to run this as an `node.js` application, in order for this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved:**
I solved this issue by adding the `Zepto` Dependencies:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.0/zepto.js" integrity="sha512-+ab24sSOgbciah+hyqPk/XqGOooAInsofud5JB4AdrRfahahDA/WWnnm6dS/bl7UmN8RW8ZGp85EoWU/aFTUhA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Furthermore, I have had to consider, that when initializing the editor, we are parsing an id for the div, so do not enter somiting link `#yourId`, use instead: `yourId`, without the #-symbol.